# Finding $a_n$ with $a_n = o(n \cdot \log(n))$ and not $O(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you give me an example of a sequence $a_n$ ($n \in \mathbb N$) that satisfies the above conditions?

$o$ and $O$ are Landau symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of functions that are not constant, but smaller than logarithm, for example:

- roots of logarithm $\sqrt{\log n}$, $\sqrt[3]{\log n}$, etc.
- double logarithm $\log \log n$, triple, etc.
- [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) $\log^* n$,
- [inverse Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Ackermann#Inverse) $\alpha(n)$,
- many, many others,
- combinations of the above.

Let $f(n)$ be such a function, then $nf(n)$ is a valid answer to your question.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 6):

All you really need to do is find a sequence that is $o(\log(n))$ but not $O(1)$ and then multiply by $n$.  The sequence  $\log \log n$ is $o(\log(n))$ and unbounded, so
$$
a_n = n \log (\log( n))
$$